# Simple HTML file

Tags: html

I am new in HTML and want to create simple file without CSS. File need to contain following text

```
Record1
    Description 1
    Description 2
    …

Record2
    Description 1
    Description 2
    …
```

Any idea how to write such simple html without additional CSS file?

Comment: research `<ul>` and `<li>`

Comment: `<pre>your manually indented content here</pre>` …?

Comment: You need to read some basic html-tutorial for beginners to figure this out. Can be found quite easily.

Comment: CSS isn't something you must use, you can create a HTML file without any CSS in it

Comment: if a `ul` doesn't do it for you then try a `dl`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: @Pete "Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: @user202729 this question shouldn't be answered as it is too broad so I am guving them a tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `ul li`

```html
<ul>
  <li>Record1</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Description 1</li>
    <li>Description 2</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Record2</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Description 1</li>
    <li>Description 2</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated here, use a list code, otherwise known as ul

```
 <ul>
 <li>Record1</li>
 <ul>
```

Repeat each ul for each record, and each li for each element.

Comment: If it is already stated (and even accepted as an answer), you do not need to answer the same thing again...